# flying saucer pdf: greek characters are not shown

Tags: java, flying-saucer

I'm creating an XHTML that contains greek characters. Find a simple example below.

```
XHMTL= "ΚΑΛΗμέρα"
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("fonts/verdana.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
renderer.setDocumentFromString(XHTML);
final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                try {
                    renderer.createPDF(baos);

                } catch (DocumentException e) {
                    jObj.put("status", 0);
                    jObj.put("error", "Could not create the file");
                    return jObj.toString();
                }
```

When I'm printing the result I'm getting `???????α`.

Any help please?

Comment: What is the flying saucer reference? Is it relevant to the question at all?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer It's the iTextRenderer

Comment: Could this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250606/generation-of-pdf-from-html-with-non-latin-characters-using-itextrenderer-does-n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found  the solution. I've changed the fonts and upload them on the server:

```
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
                    renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("/mypath/fonts/ARIALUNI.TTF",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                                
renderer.setDocumentFromString(XHTMLstring);
```