# Flying Saucer iTextPDF Chinese Fonts

Tags: java, fonts, itext, flying-saucer

I'm using FlyingSaucer (R8pre2 version) to convert an XHTML into PDF.

The HTML has Chinese characters and are using MS Mincho fonts.

The document was converted, but all the Chinese characters are missing on the converted PDF.

Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Code:

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("output.pdf");
String inputFile = "input.html";
String url = new File(inputFile).toURI().toURL().toString();
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocument(url);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os);
os.close();
```

Comment: Can you show your source codes?

Comment: Please see the updated question with the code to convert the XHTML into PDF

Comment: I didn't see you load fonts. Load Chinese fonts & ensure contents are in UTF-8. Similar case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231194/encoding-issue-while-generating-pdf-file-from-html-using-itextrenderer

Comment: I see. Chinese characters are now displayed on the generated PDF after loading the necessary fonts. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Chinese font is required to be loaded before Chinese font is displayed. For example:

```
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("fonts/TIMES.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("fonts/TIMESBD.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("fonts/TIMESBI.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("fonts/TIMESI.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

Comment: Is there any overhead of adding all the fonts? say 100 font files?

Comment: You can always time the execution time by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/180191/188331